# How to communicate properly with the Tendermint ABCI?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, tendermint

I have faced a lot of difficulty properly connecting to the Tendermint server as spawned by the `abci` Node.JS package.

I have tried following the documentation over at [the official site](https://docs.tendermint.com/master/rpc/), however I awlays get the error `Error: invalid wire type 4 at offset 3` which appears to be an issue with the protobuf and decoding the request. When I `console.log` inside the library, it appears it tries to decode a substring of the request that makes no sense.

As an example, if I send a GET request with a long `tx` parameter on `broadcast_tx_commit`, the message it tries to decode is `ET /broadcast_tx_commit?tx=0x017465` which is really weird. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been bugging me the past few days!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tendermint outside of the Cosmos SDK, this tutorial might be helpful in separating the concerns: https://github.com/6thc/tendermint-cas-demo

I know that protobuf is currently being removed from Tendermint and the Cosmos SDK so the answer to your question might actually be very different in the near future too.